# How to retrieve all the photos and videos in an array from Photos library?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, alassetslibrary

In my code I have tried to fetch all the photos from the photo library and store them in an array.
I want to fetch even the videos also and store them in the same array.
Please tell me how to modify this code for the above requirement.
I have been struggling for this since months as I am a newbie.

```
-(IBAction)getAllPictures: (id) sender
{
    imageArray=[[NSArray alloc] init];
    mutableArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray* assetURLDictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    void (^assetEnumerator)( ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
    {
        if(result != nil)
        {
            if([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto])
            {
                if([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypeVideo])
                {

                  if([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypeUnknown])
                  {
                    [assetURLDictionaries addObject:[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs]];

                    NSURL *url= (NSURL*) [[result defaultRepresentation]url];

                    [library assetForURL:url
                     resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
                     {
                         [mutableArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]]];

                         if ([mutableArray count]==count)
                         {
                             imageArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:mutableArray];
                             [self allPhotosCollected:imageArray];
                         }
                     }
                    failureBlock:^(NSError *error){ NSLog(@"operation was not successfull!");
                    } ];

        }
    }
}
}
};

NSMutableArray *assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

void (^ assetGroupEnumerator) ( ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *)= ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
{
    if(group != nil)
    {
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
        [assetGroups addObject:group];
        count=[group numberOfAssets];
    }
};

assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                       usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                     failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"There is an error");
}];
}

-(void)allPhotosCollected:(NSArray*)imgArray
{
//write your code here after getting all the photos from library...
    NSLog(@"all pictures are %@",imgArray);
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to with `xcode` or `xcode 5` these tags are reserved for issues with the `xcode IDE` itself don't use the tag just because you are using the `xcode IDE` please see wiki http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info

Answer (score 1):

You have to use assetLibraries Try this code :-

**My code for fetching all the photos from the photo library**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    xy =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSMutableArray* assetURLDictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    void (^assetEnumerator)( ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        if(result != nil) {
            if([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto]) {
                [assetURLDictionaries addObject:[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs]];

                NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);
                NSLog(@"asset URLDictionary is:%@",assetURLDictionaries);
                NSURL *url= (NSURL*) [[result defaultRepresentation]url]; 

                [library assetForURL:url
                         resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                             [xy addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]]];
                             NSLog(@" xy is:%@",xy);
                             image =[ [UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage:[xy objectAtIndex:0]];
                             NSLog(@"image is:%@",image);
                         }
                         failureBlock:^(NSError *error){ NSLog(@"test:Fail"); } ]; 
            } 
        }
    };

    NSMutableArray *assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    void (^ assetGroupEnumerator) ( ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *)= ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"hello");
        if(group != nil) {
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
            [assetGroups addObject:group];
            NSLog(@"Number of assets in group :%d",[group numberOfAssets]);
            NSLog(@"asset group is:%@",assetGroups);
        }
    };

    assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
             usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
             failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {NSLog(@"A problem occurred");}];
}
```

**My code for fetching all the videos from the library**

```
- (void)updateAssetsLibrary
{
loadImgView.hidden = NO;
[spinner startAnimating];
//selectVideoBtn .userInteractionEnabled = NO;

assetItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = assetsLibrary;

[assetLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) 
{
    if (group)
    {
        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allVideos]];
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
        {
             if (asset)
             {
                 dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                 ALAssetRepresentation *defaultRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                 NSString *uti = [defaultRepresentation UTI];
                 appDelegate.videoURL = [[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs] valueForKey:uti];

                 mpVideoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:appDelegate.videoURL];

                 NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %i", NSLocalizedString(@"Video", nil), [assetItems count]+1];

                 [self performSelector:@selector(imageFromVideoURL)];
                 [dic setValue:title forKey:kName];
                 [dic setValue:appDelegate.videoURL forKey:kURL];

                 AssetBrowserItem *item = [[AssetBrowserItem alloc] initWithURL:appDelegate.videoURL title:title];
                 [assetItems addObject:item];
                 [appDelegate.videoURLArray addObject:dic];

                 NSLog(@"Video has info:%@",appDelegate.videoURLArray);
             }
             NSLog(@"Values of dictionary==>%@", dic);

             //NSLog(@"assetItems:%@",assetItems);
             NSLog(@"Videos Are:%@",appDelegate.videoURLArray);
        } ];
    }
    // group == nil signals we are done iterating.
    else 
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //[self updateBrowserItemsAndSignalDelegate:assetItems];
            loadImgView.hidden = NO;
            [spinner stopAnimating];
            [loadImgView removeFromSuperview];
            //selectVideoBtn .userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        });
    }
}
failureBlock:^(NSError *error) 
{
    NSLog(@"error enumerating AssetLibrary groups %@\n", error);
}];
}

- (UIImage *)imageFromVideoURL 
{
// result 
UIImage *image = nil;

// AVAssetImageGenerator
AVAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:appDelegate.videoURL options:nil];; 
AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;

// calc midpoint time of video
Float64 durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds([asset duration]);
CMTime midpoint = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(durationSeconds/2.0, 600); 

// get the image from 
NSError *error = nil; 
CMTime actualTime;
CGImageRef halfWayImage = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:midpoint actualTime:&actualTime error:&error];

if (halfWayImage != NULL) 
{
    // CGImage to UIImage
    image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:halfWayImage];
    [dic setValue:image forKey:kImage];
    NSLog(@"Values of dictionary==>%@", dic);
    NSLog(@"Videos Are:%@",appDelegate.videoURLArray);
    CGImageRelease(halfWayImage);
}
return image;
}

- (void)assetsLibraryDidChange:(NSNotification*)changeNotification
{
[self updateAssetsLibrary];
}

- (void)buildAssetsLibrary
{
assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
ALAssetsLibrary *notificationSender = nil;

NSString *minimumSystemVersion = @"4.1";
NSString *systemVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
if ([systemVersion compare:minimumSystemVersion options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
    notificationSender = assetsLibrary;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(assetsLibraryDidChange:) name:ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification object:notificationSender];
[self updateAssetsLibrary];
}
```

This code will give u list of videos of your iPhone.

It may help you :)

[For Future Reference Use this:-](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Yes I have used ALAssetsLibrary and I think the code which you have provided will fetch me only videos not photos as well.

Comment: @vanya Updated the Answer, Check out!

Comment: Do you worry about memory usage when you're essentially putting all the the photos (full resolution) into the memory as an array of uiimage? Reason I asked is I'm trying to save the ALAsset that gets returned instead and only load the uiimage (lazily) when the collectionViewCell is displayed (for thumbnail) and when the user decided to select a particular photo (for full resolution).

Comment: I recommend storing just an array of ALAsset's, then loading lazily Ben mentions. An ALAssset has a thumbnail property which returns a thumbnail size image around 150x150, which will work great for most views. This lazy loading is fast and I don't see any slowdown or lag in my views. An important note is that if you're storing ALAsset's they're only valid for the lifetime of the ALAssetLibrary that you got them from, so keep that around.

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer very simple and easy to understand

```js
-(void)getFromGallery:(BOOL )IsImages
{
    if(self.csCollectionsArray != nil)
        [self.csCollectionsArray removeAllObjects];
    __block NSMutableDictionary *date = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    ALAssetsLibrary *csAssetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    NSUInteger groupTypes = ALAssetsGroupAlbum | ALAssetsGroupEvent | ALAssetsGroupFaces | ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos;
    [csAssetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:groupTypes usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
    {
        if([group numberOfAssets] > 0)
        {
            if(IsImages)
                [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
            else
                [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allVideos]];
            [group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
            {
                if(asset)
                { //1.fetching all assets from device library
                    //2.Add all fetched assests from library
                    [date setObject:asset forKey:[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate]];
                }
            }];
        }
        else
        { NSLog(@"---> load table -------->");
            if(date != nil && date.count > 0)
            { //3.Sort using date by ascending order and moved to dictionary to array
                NSArray *sortedKeys = [[date allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
                for (NSString *key in sortedKeys)
                    [self.csCollectionsArray addObject: [date objectForKey:key]];
                //4.Load images into collection view after fetching all datas
                [self reloadCollectionView];
                if(self.csCollectionView != nil)
                    [self.csCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:([self.csCollectionsArray count] - 1) inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
            }
            date = nil;
        }
    }failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
    {
        if((csCollectionsArray == nil || [csCollectionsArray count] == 0))
        {
            ALAuthorizationStatus status = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus]; if(status != ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
            {
                [self showAlertAndCloseUploaderView:@"You can just go to \"Settings\" app (General -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy) then come again and click ok when the alert dialog is showing for enable the permission to access the photo library"];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```